# Accesing private static properties via Closures - is it rational?

Tags: php, oop, closures

I intend to create classes that contain pure immutable data, and simple trait (or class, it's not the point) to access it. So, dummy code to illustrate what I mean:

```
//Data class
class DataStorage
{
    use DataHandler;

    static private $dataStorage = [
        'key' => 'data'
    ];
}
```

Trait to obtain data:

```
//Data getter
trait DataHandler
{
    static public function get($property)
    {
        $func = function() use($property) {
            return self::$dataStorage[$property];
        };

        $obtain = Closure::bind($func, NULL, get_class());

        return $obtain();
    }
}
```

As you can see, `Closure` is used to obtain data that is private, it's quite simple and fits my requirements. However, this approach seems somewhat dangerous. It looks like that way I could access *ANY* static private property of *ANY* class.

**Q1**: Does it go against principles of OOP?

**Q2**: Is it good solution to artificially restrict usage of this trait by making `DataStorage` class as such that implements some interface and just check it in `DataHandler::get()` method?

Sorry if my question is dumb, in this case I would also greatly appreciate constructive critics.

Comment: Well, then you also just could declare your properties as public... (Assuming you have some similar mechanism for setting them). So, it just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Not much point of making a property `private` if you want direct access to it.  Simply provide a `public` getter method or make the property `public` itself.

Comment: I want read-only access to it, actually, and I want kind of unified mechanism to do it, because there could be a lot of those `DataStorage` classes. If it just a getter method, then probably `return self::` on non-existing variable will throw warnings. Well, maybe I'm indeed confused here...

Comment: I assume the data to make read only is coming in on the fly and that is why you aren't using constants, yes?

Comment: Yes, this is one of the reasons. Also, storing an array or object in constant is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot understand your argumentation of using closure. Anyway you could rewrite it without Closure.

```
class DataStorage {
    use DataHandler;
    static private $dataStorage = [
        'key' => 'data'
    ];
    }

trait DataHandler {
    static public function get($property) {
        return self::$dataStorage[$property];
        }
    }

echo DataStorage::get('key');
```

http://3v4l.org/FOTob#v540

P.S. It's better to avoid static values, it's bring some disadvantages from global variable like *tight coupling*.

Answer (score 0):

The OOP visibility is there to help you code a better system through object encapsulation. It's not bulletproof.

> *It's harder, though not impossible, to abuse. A determined individual*
> *can write garbage code in any language.*
>
> [Allen Holub](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001REFS14)

Comment: Then why there are so many examples of such `Closure` usage in the Web, say, on php.net? I believe that allowing to write something to the sensitive data by accident could be more of an abuse...

Comment: Modifying the private property of an object from the outside is wrong. It's possible, but wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say accessing the private property... or anything private. That's the whole point of private.

Comment: Then I don't understand point of common get/set methods inside the classes (mentioned in many guides and implemented in many systems), that actually allow you to access private properties.